# Wrong 2nd argument Android Studios (Speech to Text)

Tags: android, error-handling

I am facing problems implementing a speech to text). I got an error in the line where my "startActivity" is, for error log see below the code:

```
public void promptSpeechInput(){
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "say something");

   try{
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
           startActivity(i, 100); // ERROR
       }
   }

    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type: Found: 'int', required: 'android.os.Bundle'
```

How to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you don't need to set additional options for the created activity so I would suggest changing the startActivity call to  `startActivity(i);`

If however you need to pass additional data to the newly created activity - consult the Activity class documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)